# Convert UNIX time (INT) to timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, unix-timestamp, epoch, datetime-conversion

I have a column "date_time" in a BigQuery table which contains unix timestamp values like "1569888224". The problem is that these values are integer data types, not timestamp data types, so I do not seem to have an easy way to convert them to human readable date/times. Does anyone have a good way of converting these integers into datetime values in BigQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

This can be solved by using BigQuery's TIMESTAMP_SECONDS function - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp

```
select TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(date_time) from table;
```

Comment: Correct link for the function is https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_seconds

Comment: It depends on the source data.  Epoch time from Cisco required TIMESTAMP_MILLIS not TIMESTAMP_SECONDS

Answer (score 8):

A shortcut to anyone who is trying to convert a **Firebase** event_timestamp in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(event_timestamp as INT64)/1000000 as INT64)) as converted,
event_timestamp,
event_date
FROM [table] LIMIT 10
```

Comment: an even better one is

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as converted,
event_timestamp,
event_date
FROM [table] LIMIT 10```

Answer (score 4):

Depend on your column values, but in general int64 values consist of 16 digits such as;

```
- event_timestamp
- user_first_touch_timestamp
- etc...
```

you should use below functions;

```
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) event_datetime    
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp) user_first_touch
```

if it doesn't consist of 16 digits, you can try the other functions which one is suitable for you;

```
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the timestamp of your preference; here I have used IST(Indian Standard Time):

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(Column_Name) AS unix_timestamp,
  CONCAT(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(Column_Name), 'Asia/Kolkata'), ' IST') AS IST_timestamp
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_Table_Name*`
```